# Same query & data but different results after change of server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, version

I have below query (made for me by a developer), which i've previously only ran on my old server which was running 5.7.31 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
I've now changed server to: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

on the old server the results are what i expect and the 'CHOICE' column correctly marks rows as e.g. CHOICE1/2 AND CHOICE2/2
but on the new server the 'CHOICE' column is only givING CHOICE1/2 CHOICE1/2 and every choice is 1 of

also the outputted number of rows is weird also. the parts_v6b table is 112929 rows.
for old server the query returns 126362 rows, and on the mariadb server it has 134844 rows.

like i said i didnt write the query, i only need to use it. it purpose is to mark and number the 'CHOICES' in the data rows.

here's the query:

```
 Select
    a.ArtNr,
    a.CHOICEPIVOT,
    a.PIVOT,
    if(a.choices=1,'',concat(a.choice_prefix,a.choices)) as CHOICE
from (
        select c.*,d.choices from (select b.*, 
        concat('CHOICE',@r:= IF(@u = CHOICEPIVOT, @r + 1,1),'/') as choice_prefix,
        @u:= CHOICEPIVOT as CHOICEPIVOT_1
    from (select * from parts_v6b order by CHOICEPIVOT asc) as b,
    (select @r:= 1) AS r,
    (select @u:= 0) AS u) as c
    left join (select CHOICEPIVOT,count(*) as choices from parts_v6b group by CHOICEPIVOT order by CHOICEPIVOT asc) as d
    on c.CHOICEPIVOT_1=d.CHOICEPIVOT
) as a;
```

Comment: Same starting data plus same querying logic should absolutely at least yield a result set with the same number of records.  Possible differences could arise due to things like floating point precision, especially in the case where one of the two queries uses it, while the other uses an exact type.  But basically, I don't expect to see your current observations.

Comment: The query uses user-defined variables in the subquery. This type of query needs definite rows processing order - i.e. the subquery must include ORDER BY clause which provides deterministic ordering, which needs the sorting expression which' value is unique over processed rowset. But such ordering is absent - so the output is non-deterministic. And the whole query is logically incorrect. Add ORDER BY clause to the subquery with alias `c`.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECTs` with @variables should not be trusted.  The Optimizer may perform the query in an unexpected way, leading to strange results.

5.7 and 10.3 have radically different Optimizers.  (They started a major divergence at 5.6 / 10.0.)

Do `EXPLAIN SELECT`; you may see some of the differences.

Technically, a subquery delivers an unordered set.  That is, the Optimizer is free to throw away an `ORDER BY` in a subquery.  This is likely to mess up certain usage of @variables.  MariaDB threw away the `ORDER BY` long ago.  MySQL followed suit later.  Some more discussion:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/